# Call to Synchronization/wait?

Tags: java, multithreading

Could anyone just help me understand this?

If we have a class:

```
public class Sample{
 public synchronized method1(){ //Line1
  ....
  wait(); //Line2
  ....
 }
}
```

Now, when 3 new threads try to call the method 'method1' on the same object

```
Sample s = new Sample();
Thread t1 = new Thread(); // t2 and t3
```

and inside run method of each of these threads, we call s.method1().
So, how does it work here? When t1 accesses method1, it goes in the method and calls wait. What about the rest of the threads when it tries to access method1?

Do they get blocked on the method1 since synchronization allows only one thread to access the object instance at a time? Or do they go to wait state?

Comment: They'll eventually all be `wait()`ing, since you're not providing a `notify()` anywhere. Read the tutorials for `wait/notify` to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lock is obtained on object. In this case since there is only one object `s` on which all the threads are trying to call same method `method1` hence only one thread can enter in the method.

> What about the rest of the threads when it tries to access method1?

You are calling `wait` on this object, hence *lock is released* and other threads will get *chance* but in last all 3 threads will reach in *block state* because there is no one to `notify` it.

Nothing will be executed after `wait()` statement for all 3 threads.

> Do they get blocked on the method1 since synchronization allows only one thread to access the object instance at a time?

`wait()` release the lock hence this will not block other thread to access the same method but if you are not calling `notify` then in last all threads will enter in blocked state.

Try to visualize it

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The key part is that wait() will release the monitor that the calling thread is synchronizing against, thus allowing other threads in to the same synchronized block.

However, be warned that it will not release any other monitors that are also held by that thread, which is can lead to [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).  This is why nesting synchronized calls can be dangerous.

This monitor behaviour is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29)

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread
>   releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread
>   notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either
>   through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The
>   thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and
>   resumes execution.